# Apache2: Webpage is only accessible via localhost but not via custom domain or IP address

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I'm just starting to learn Apache server.

I installed `apache2(version 2.4.41)` based on Ubuntu, WSL2 Windows10 and followed [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install_apache_web_server_ubuntu/) to set up a webpage.

I created a webpage for testing. The path is:

```
/var/www/info.dev/html/index.html
```

The issue is, after I followed the tutorial step by step, my webpage only works via `localhost`:

[image: localhost img]

This is my `/etc/hosts` file:

[image: host img]

My `info.dev.conf` file:

[image: config img]

It won't work if I use a custom domain like `info.dev` or `www.info.dev`:
[image: domainimg]

If I use a local IP address, I get this error: [image: ip img]

I've been stuck in this issue for several days and tried every solution I could google, but it seems like none of them works for me. I'll really appreciate it if someone could save my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the myriad of images you've shared, I would venture that you've edited the "wrong" `hosts` file. Rather than change the one in Ubuntu, you need to edit the one in Windows found at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. In there, you can add your records.

Replace:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

With:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.0.1        info.dev

::1              localhost
::1              info.dev
```

You do not need to have a record for subdomains such as `www.info.dev`. Be sure to replace `127.0.0.1` with the IP address of your WSL2 Ubuntu instance. You can find this by typing: `wsl hostname -I` from PowerShell or Command Prompt.

In your Apache configuration file, you can update the `ServerAlias` to include a wildcard to ensure that all traffic for the domain is routed correctly:

```
ServerAlias info.dev *.info.dev
```

Having `info.dev` in both `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` is fine. You can exclude it from the alias if you prefer.

Comment: PS when using a _hosts_ file for name resolution, the _hosts_ file should be shared onto all computers within your LAN. Make sure some stupid Windows "antivirus/firewall"-software doesn't block your Windows _hosts_ file.

Comment: Thanks, matigo. After I modify the hosts file, local IP address works for my own page. But when I tried to use localhost, the web page is redirected to IIS windows page and when I tried custom domain info.dev, error prompts "Your connection is not private".

Comment: @nickwfj123 — Is your WSL2 environment accessible to Windows with `127.0.0.1` or is it using a different IP address?

Comment: @matigo - I'm not sure if we are saying the same IP address. I got it by the command: hostname -I, which is different from 127.0.0.1. A new problem I just found is when I remove these modifies above in hosts file, custom domain works, but only at the first time I open a new tab. Then if I refresh the page, something goes wrong again. error prompts "This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in www.info.dev."

Comment: `localhost` will — ideally — only ever point to `127.0.0.1`, so typing this into a browser on a system that is not the server will not work. You will need to use the custom domain(s) that you set up. The error you see with `www` is also likely due to the hosts file on your Windows machine. You will need a line with the WSL instance’s IP for each subdomain.

Comment: Thanks. A line with local IP and subdomain pair works now. Does this mean I have to manually  modify the hosts file each time I wanna generate new domains? I'm wondering if there is a way I can do via Ubuntu or something else to make the hosts file automatically set up.

Comment: I would strongly discourage having automated systems in WSL (or anywhere else) automatically update the `hosts` file on your Windows machine. There is a reason why one must be Admin to edit that file, and it’s not good to leave yourself open to DNS hijacking …